Measure capacitance on live circuit
Is there any LCR meter on the market that allows a user to measure capacitance on a live circuit without disconnecting it from power?

There might be but it depends on what capacitance you want to measure and why. Do you want to measure capacitance of an actual capacitor (from picofarads to millifarads) or say stray capacitance of a digital input pin and PCB trace leading to a connector pin? In the latter case, it's routinely done.

Can you measure both the current through it and voltage across it while in circuit? Does it have any ripple during operation?

@Justme It is to measure the capacitance of an actual capacitor

@winny Unfortunately I cannot. I failed to mention that a client of mine wanted me to look for that LCR meter.

Well, the ”LCR meter” could be a current camp plus two alligator leads.

No, because this is physically impossible. There is no way, in the general case, to isolate the capacitor from the effects of the rest of the circuit without somehow disconnecting at least one of its terminals.
In very restricted cases it may be possible, with increased difficulty, to make a measurement with (drastically) reduced precision. If you know for a fact that the impedance of the rest of the circuit is very high at the meter's test frequency, for instance. Or if it's a completely passive circuit, you know the full circuit schematic including values of all other components, and are willing to do some math. Or if the circuit has some behaviour that can be directly related to the capacitance (e.g. a ringing frequency), you can make multiple measurements with additional capacitance added and work backwards from there.
Just desolder the part before measuring it. It's much easier.

And now I realize you're talking about an even worse case, where the capacitor isn't just in a circuit, but in a live circuit, which is even less possible.

Depending on the voltage levels involved, it may be possible to find an instrument that will not be damaged when you attempt the measurement.
In some (rare?) cases it may be possible to do an accurate measurement. Even after thinking about the circuit, I would regard any measurement of this type as suspect.

It is for 10V and 1µF max. I agree that it is suspect
